# Nodejs reply topic when replicate pod on k8s

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm using kafkajs for connect to kafka broker server with connection like this

```
import { Kafka, KafkaConfig } from 'kafkajs';
import { CLIENT_ID, KAFKA_BROKER } from '../config';

const kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig = {
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  brokers: [KAFKA_BROKER as string],
}

export const kafka = new Kafka(kafkaConfig)
```

and using reply topic for getting reply

```
export const getResult = async <T>(messageOption: MessageOption, data: any) => {
    const processID = v4()
    let payload = JSON.stringify(data)
    const replyTopic = messageOption.replyTopic ?? `${messageOption.sendTopic}.reply`
    console.log('publishing message to ' + messageOption.sendTopic)
    
    await producer.send({
      topic: messageOption.sendTopic,
      messages: [
        {
          key: processID, value: payload,
          headers: {
            'kafka_replyTopic': replyTopic,
            'kafka_correlationId': processID
          }
        }],
    });

    return await getMessageResponse<T>(
      replyTopic,
      processID,
      messageOption.timer
    );
}
```

When application running in single node the application working fine but when running on k8s and replica node to 2 node the reply message will randomly enter to some node, since the node that wait for replying can't get the message back